# Good Way to Handle dynamic infograph with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've currently been assigned a project to create the following with javascript, you can view the final product here: http://i1245.photobucket.com/albums/gg583/leetpete1994/Infografic-TrafficSources_zpsf50dfa6d.png

It's basically my job to take the provided PDF and create a way to dynamically display the data that the image conveys. The data itself is going to be calculated elsewhere, so all I have to worry about is accepting the values for each beaker, and filling them appropriately.

My idea right now:

Right now my idea is using the canvas. I've created a beaker class, and then made the 5 beakers an instance of the class. This works pretty well, and I'm sitting with a canvas that has 5 empty beakers in the correct place. I've divided each beaker by 100; then I can fill each one correctly the amount of pixels needed to be whatever percent it happens to be, but this is where I run into issues. Each beaker is a different shape, and as each one gets filled the shape changes. Therefore, I'm having a difficult time trying to actually draw in the liquid in the beakers. Secondly, if I do manage to draw the liquid in correctly, it's going to cover details of the beaker. If I did liquid first then beakers it would be the opposite problem. I've also tried using two canvases stacked and controlling the opacity of the liquid, but haven't had any luck getting the effect I want to achieve.

So, is there a better way to go about doing this, or to easily draw the odd shapes onto the canvas? I'm beginning to think using the canvas is not going to be the best way. I know I could just make several images for each at different liquid levels, but I want to avoid using that many images in the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use a ***reveal*** approach to the problem...

One image for the each empty beaker, and one image for each of the full liquid with details of the beaker.

Then position the liquid image at the bottom and reveal as many pixel upwards as you want..

```
<div class="beaker">
    <div class="liquid"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
.beaker, .liquid {
    background: url('path-to-sprite-image.png') 0 100% no-repeat;
    width:130px;
}
.beaker {
    height:280px;
    position:relative;
}
.liquid {
    background-position: right 100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Simple demo at http://jsfiddle.net/27E5q/

Comment: I like the idea of this, but my problem arises with the hidding of the liquid. I have three things to display, the beaker, background, and liquid, and so far I've yet to come up with a decent scheme to display them all correctly. Is there perhaps a way to set the transparency of a certain color in a certain area to none? Then I could simple start with the full beakers and make areas of them transparent?

Comment: @PeterJewicz added simple code and demo.. you could use .png files for transparency.. all you need is the beaker empty and the beaker full with liquid. You overlap the beaker with the liquid (*which includes the beaker as well*) and reveal only the part of the liquid you want.. (*demo values might be weird due to image used - found through google..*)

Answer (score 1):

**Here’s a way using Canvas to get the effect you desire:**

- Draw the image with the beakers being transparent
- Gradually draw the original image from the bottom to the top
- Thereby filling the transparent beakers with fluid.

[image]

[image]

You can take more time than I did at making the beakers transparent ;)

And of course, you could divide the drawing into columns and fill the beakers at any rate you need.

If you need different colors to fill the beakers, you can use context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over".  This compositing mode allows you to "draw under" an existing drawing (the new color will only fill the *transparent pixels* on the existing image).

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Enyjb/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red; border-radius:15px;}
    canvas{position:absolute;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();


    // draw a background that fills the beakers with gray
    var background=document.getElementById("background");
    var bkCtx=background.getContext("2d");
    bkCtx.fillStyle="rgb(234,234,234)";
    bkCtx.fillRect(0,0,background.width,background.height);

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var y;

    var img1=new Image();
    img1.onload=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);
        y=img1.height-50;
        img2=new Image();
        img2.onload=function(){
            animate();
        }
        img2.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/temp01.png";
    }
    img1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/temp02.png";


    var fps = 30;
    function animate() {
        setTimeout(function() {

            if(y<100){return;}

            requestAnimFrame(animate);

            // Drawing code goes here
            y-=1;
            ctx.drawImage(img2,
                          0,y,img2.width,img2.height-y,
                          0,y,img2.width,img2.height-y)


        }, 1000 / fps);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="background" width=1024 height=327></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=1024 height=327></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on data visualization, and this might be an overkill - but - you might want to consider using D3.js:

http://d3js.org/

It's a pretty slick library for drawing data. Super cool, and looks super easy.

Here's a gallery \ examples page: [Gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

*And no, I'm not affiliated with D3.js in any way (-!

Good luck!